# How do you divide the string in pumping lemma?

Tags: regular-language, computation-theory

For example, let us prove L = {0^n1^n | n ≥ 0} is irregular.

To prove a language is irregular, disprove any one of:
(1) |uv| ≤ n
(2) |v| ≥ 1
(3) for all i ≥ 0: uviw ∈ L such that | uviw | >= n

Let us assume that L is regular, then by Pumping Lemma the above given rules follow.
Now, let x ∈ L and |x| ≥ n. So, by Pumping Lemma, there exists u, v, w such that (1) – (3) hold.

We show that for all u, v, w, (1) – (3) does not hold.

If (1) and (2) hold then x = 0^n1^n = uvw with |uv| ≤ n and |v| ≥ 1.

//How did you divide the string of the language? How w = 0^c1^n?

So, u = 0^a, v = 0^b, w = 0^c1^n where : a + b ≤ n, b ≥ 1, c ≥ 0, a + b + c = n

Thanks
Rahman

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `n` for two things: in the defintion of the language as well as for the constant of the pumping lemma. Let us use `n_0` for the constant. In your condition (iii) the last statement should be `|uvw| \geq n_0` without the exponent `i`.

Now we can choose, for example, the word `a^{n_0}b^{n_0}`, which fulfills this length requirement. From the condition `|uv|\leq n_0` we directly see that `u` and `v` consist only of symbols `a` for every factorization that fulfills the conditions of the pumping lemma. So any word in `uv^iw` for `i>1` will have more `a` than `b` and thus not be in the language, which contradicts the condition number three.